# git pull automatic merge list of merges

Tags: git

When I do git pull, I get nano opened that asks me to write down comment for automatic merge. 
Problem is I'm never shown what is merged, how the hell am I supposed to comment it?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which version of git do you use? Also do you have any hooks set up for your instance of git?

Comment: Do a `fetch` instead, and then `diff` the current brach with its remote.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the configuration option `merge.log`:

```
git config [--global] merge.log true
```

With that option enabled, Git will render a summary of all merged commits into the default commit message of a merge commit:

```
Merge branch 'foo'

* foo: (413 commits)
  Subject of 1st commit
  Subject of 2nd commit
  and so on
```